# PostgreSQL - Locking a Table That Is Almost Never Changed

Tags: postgresql

I'm a software developer and I'm trying to implement a job board website for my own experience and learning.

One of the entities of this database is **industry**. And **companies** can be associated with industries. A company is typically associated with 2-3 industries and an industry can be associated with many companies, yielding a many-to-many relation.

I'm planning to insert a list of industries into the industry table, so the application comes with a pre-defined list of industries and companies can choose between these industries.

After insertion of industries, they're never changed in the future. Is it possible to somehow **enable a lock on the industry table** and **avoid inserts/updates/deletes**?

I believe it's safer this way, and in the rare case of a future insert/update/delete, the lock can be disabled and re-enabled when the change is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, don't think about *preventing* access.
Think about only *granting* the access that is required.

If you only want select access to that table, then only grant select access.
If you *do* need update access (and remember that an *Application* feature that allows the addition of Industries would need this as well) then grant that.

This suggests that you have two "sets" of Users for this data - those who can only read it and those that can update it.
I would suggest that you create Groups (non-logon Users in Postgresql), grant the necessary privileges to each Groups and then grant those Groups to the [many] Users that will need them.

Also, I would also suggest it's better *not* to create individual database accounts for every Application user.  Use a dedicated database account for the Application and manage users account as regular data.

Comment: @Thanks for the thorough explanation.